# How to show $M$ is a finitely generated $A$-module?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, etale-cohomology

[image]

In Corollary 1.2.3, in order to apply Nakayama's lemma, how to show $M$ is a finitely generated $A$-module?

Comment: $M$ is not necessarily f.g. as $A$-module! But if $M=mM$, then $M=nM$.